# UK m590e, Use GSM,GSM compact or UTRAN? (AT+COPS)

Tags: sensors, mobile-data

I am based in the UK.
I am using an **M590e** module for a remote weather station. Which parameter should I use for the `AT+COPS` command? GSM, GSM compact or UTRAN?

Which are available in the UK? Which ones will give me TCP/IP ("The internet")?

Which is the best to use for IoT? Is it different for different providers?

Comment: Please add the relevant datasheet and documentation links to your question.

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking your carrier? I mean whoever provided your SIM Card ... Vodafone, 3 ... Or don't you have one yet & are you asking us to 1) to recommend a carrier and then 2)  tell you how to connect?

Answer (score 7):

You can check the possible options, if you have a working setup, by the following command :

AT+COPS=?

It will give you the available carriers and the available options usable with them.

Answer format is:

```
+COPS: [list of supported (<stat>,long alphanumeric
               <oper>,short alphanumeric <oper>,numeric <oper>
              [,<AcT>])s][,,(list of supported <mode>s),(list of  supported <format>s)]
```

An example answer:

```
 AT+COPS=? +COPS: (1,"E-Plus",,"26203"),(1,"Telekom.de",,"26201"), (1,"Vodafone.de",,"26202"),(1,"o2 - de",,"26207"),,(0-4),(0,2)
```

tells that supported modes are 0-4, values from this table:

```
0 GSM
1 GSM Compact
2 UTRAN
3 GSM w/EGPRS
4 UTRAN w/HSDPA
5 UTRAN w/HSUPA
6 UTRAN w/HSDPA and HSUPA
7 E-UTRAN
```

**Sources:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345651/atcommand-atcops-gives-undefined-return

http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/atcops-plmn-selection/

Comment: Cool, not in the data sheet for the M590E. AT+COPS=?

+COPS: (1,"T-Mobile UK","TMO UK","23430"),(1,"vodafone UK","voda UK","23415"),(2,"O2 - UK","O2 -UK","23410")